# How to render one-click unsubscribe visible on emails with Gmail and Yahoo

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscribe, gmail

Does anyone know how to render One-click unsubscribe visible on Gmail or Yahoo emails?
I have already put the code below on our html header but nothing displayed when consulting Yahoo or Gmail:
List-Unsubscribe:
mailto:listrequest@example.com?subject=unsubscribe,
https://example.com/unsubscribe.html?opaque=123456789
List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click
I also understood that Marketing cloud already has a one-click unsub set up by default on transactional send classification.
But I want to know how to display the unsubscription link on my communications.
[image]

Thank you for your help.